# Change dropdown size for .NET touchscreen application

Tags: .net, drop-down-menu, touchscreen

I'm trying to create a .NET touchscreen application. I would like to be able to create a large dropdown. By increasing the font size, the button stays the same width but increases in height, meaning it's long and thin. Is there a way to 'scale up' .NET controls so they are large in size for touchscreen applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're writing a touchscreen application, all you have to do is change the system settings on windows to make everything larger.